# How do i make my answer look like [z1, z2 ...]

Tags: java

I am working on a program. I have gotten to my end result but not the format that is required. My requirement is that the output should be formatted like [z1, z2 ...]

```
public class Range {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your frist number.");
        int input1 = red(console);

        System.out.println("Please input your second number.");
        int input2 = red(console);
        printRange(input1, input2);
    }

    public static int red(Scanner console) {
        int x = console.nextInt();
        return x;
    }

    public static void printRange(int input1, int input2) {

        if (input1 > input2) {
            for (int Z = input1; Z >= input2; Z--) {
                System.out.print("[" + Z + "]");
            }
        } 
        else if (input1 < input2) {
            for (int Z = input1; Z <= input2; Z++) {
                System.out.print("[" + Z + "]");
            }
        } 
        else {
            System.out.print("[" + input1 + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's java and it can't run using snippets. Also I've retagged it.

Comment: Wonderful indentation, won't confuse you at all ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the below code, hope that's what you need:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Range {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your frist number.");
        int input1 = red(console);
        System.out.println("Please input your second number.");
        int input2 = red(console);
        printRange(input1, input2);
    }

    public static int red(Scanner console) {
        int x = console.nextInt();
        return x;
    }

    public static void printRange(int input1, int input2) {
        System.out.print("[");

        if (input1 > input2) {
            for (int Z = input1; Z >= input2; Z--) {
                if(Z != input1){
                    System.out.print( ", " );
                }
                System.out.print( Z );
            }
        } else if (input1 < input2) {
            for (int Z = input1; Z <= input2; Z++) {
                if(Z != input1){
                    System.out.print( ", " );
                }
                System.out.print( Z );
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print( input1 );
        }
        System.out.print( "]" );
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
Explanation: Here is what it takes to get you the desired output.

1. When you said that you want all your numbers enclosed in [], all you need to do is get the brackets out of the loop so they are printed only once. Opening bracket before adding the numbers and closing bracket after the numbers are added.
2. When you want to add the list of string in the brackets, you will need the separator (,) between two numbers. Hence I have added a print statement before adding each number. The if condition restricts the adding of separator before the first number.

Comment: Thank you, it was a spot on end product that I was looking for, but i would like to know if there is anyway i could get a explanation of how you got it it to turn out this was for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void printRange(int e, int r){
    int [] result = new int[1];
    if(e<r){
        result = new int[r-e];
        for(int i=0;i<(r-e);i++)
            result[i]=e+i+1;
    }else if(r<e){
        result = new int[e-r];
        for(int j=0;j<(e-r);j++)
            result[j]=r+j+1;
    }else
        result[0]=e;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```